# Beamer itemize vspacing glue?

Tags: beamer, itemize, glue

I use a lot of itemized bullet points in presentations.  Ideally, beamer would know that when I use many bullets, space needs to be tighter than when I just a a few bullet points...sort of like glue.  I am thinking that defining the \itemsep and parskip spaces as glue could do this?!  is there a recommended style for someone who understands typography better than me---although presumably presentations are not exactly as typography sensitive as text.

advice appreciated

sincerely, /iaw

Comment: I think you're asking both what good style/typography for presentations is, and how to achieve it in Beamer. Is that correct?

Comment: An example of glue would be 1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt, which can expand from 0pt to 2pt.  Another example is 0pt plus 1fil which is the same as \hfil of \vfil.

Comment: related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148365/how-do-i-ask-beamer-to-exactly-fill-up-a-slide and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5168/spread-bullet-points-across-block-in-slide-using-beamer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, in a presentation the best solution is always **reduce the number of items and the text of the items**.  Decrease the font size or the vertical spacing is always a bad idea. You want cath the people attention highlighting the main points of what you are speaking, not anesthetize to the audience with unreadable and irrelevant text. Ideally should be not more that five-six items of one-two lines per slide.

Said that, if absolutely necessary, of course, you can use some like   `\itemsep 1em plus 5em minus 1em`  but there are also Beamer alternatives taking into account all the frame text, not only the lists:

(1) The frame option  `[squeeze]` to reduce to zero the vertical space in enumerations or itemizations and reduce the vertical spaces in the text as much as possible.

(2)  If that is not enough, much worse, you can use some like `[shrink=5]` to  shrunk the text of the frame in a 5%.  Note that this affect also the horizontal spacing (is explained in the manual why this happen). The own Beamer manual says  that this option is "very evil" and is true. Use it judiciously.

(3) Another approach for a irreducible list is split the frame with `[allowframebreaks]`. Indeed better that (1) and (2) for a long list.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[squeeze]
\begin{itemize}
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[shrink=50]
\begin{itemize}
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\begin{itemize}
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\item xxxx 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this also work in the other direction: if you have only two or three items then there is a larger space between them?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Do yo mean the glue of `\itemsep`? No doubt that  set it to  `1em plus 5em minus 1em`  does this,  but you can use also `1em plus 0em minus 1em` or  simply `1em minus 1em`.